# Is it possible to use two characters (e.g. ^tm) in insert mode in zsh for a command binding?

Tags: zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, vi-mode

in my current `.zshrc` file I have

`bindkey -M viins -s '^tm' '^[Iman ^[Ela ^[d$'`

and this doesn't work, however when I remove **m** from the shortcut
and it is now only `^t` the shortcut is working.
I'd like to have it `^tm`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It works, but you have to be quick. You can bind sequence of characters, but the idea is to bind that to *keys* that send sequences of characters.

For instance, when you press the <kbd>Home</kbd> key, many terminals send `^[[1~`. The first character there is ESC which is also bound in vi insert mode. So it's important that binding something on `ESC[1~` doesn't stop `ESC` alone from working.

`zsh` uses the `$KEYTIMEOUT` setting (0.4 second by default) to decide how long to wait for the next key to decide if it's a multi-character key press, or several single-character key presses in sequence.

Now, if there's no other key mapping that starts with `^T`, and in particular, if there's no mapping on `^T` alone, then `zsh` can wait indefinitely for that `m`. `^T` happens to be mapped to `self-insert` in the default viins keymap which is not very useful. So you can simply remove it:

```
bindkey -Mviins -r '^T'
```

Which should do what you want.

By the way, you may want to bind that to the `run-help` widget instead.

Comment: If I might ask: how can I check it any shortcut is already used the default viins keymap? I might conclude it from the behaviour that it is not working when a new key is assigned :)

Comment: @Jakub, if you want to list the current bindings, just run `bindkey` or `bindkey -M viins` for the `viins` map specifically. With `-L` for a listing as `bindkey` commands.